# How to process list of gcp points in gdal in python?

Tags: python, gdal, csv, geopandas, georeferencing

I have gcp points that I am exporting from QGIS and I would like to georeference several maps using the gdal module in python by using these points.

The following is the code to read the gcp points from the csv file and they will be used for transforming the data in the gdal function.

```
import pandas as pd
f=pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/00390_00390_modified.tif.points")
keep_col = ['mapX','mapY','pixelX', 'pixelY', 'enable', 'dX','dY', 'residual']
new_f = f[keep_col]
df = new_f.drop(columns=['enable','dX', 'dY', 'residual'])
#df['gcp']='-gcp'
#df['end']='\ '
#print(df)
col=['pixelY','pixelX','mapX','mapY']
modified_df = df[col]
modified_df['pixelY'] = modified_df['pixelY'] + 1200
new_df= modified_df.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/modified.csv', index=False)
print(modified_df[col])
```

The output of this code is,

```
        pixelY       pixelX          mapX          mapY
0    553.956835    19.352518  6.776477e+06  3.485354e+06
1    879.496403   663.237410  7.781406e+06  4.026885e+06
2   1053.776978   752.446043  7.925402e+06  4.306009e+06
3    751.618705  1047.230216  8.385932e+06  3.806277e+06
4    340.467626   674.208633  7.795048e+06  3.193823e+06
```

These will be the input ground control points to the !gdaltranslate function.

Is there any method to insert the coordinates in between -gcp and frontslash?

I tried a lot, but unfortunately, both reading data and processing them through pandas data frame and CSV aren't working.

```
!gdal_translate \
-gcp    553.9568345 19.35251799 6776477.033 3485353.556 \
-gcp    879.4964029 663.2374101 7781405.588 4026884.535 \
-gcp    1053.776978 752.4460432 7925401.709 4306008.844 \
-gcp    751.618705  1047.230216 8385931.623 3806277.157 \
-gcp    340.4676259 674.2086331 7795047.763 3193823.491 \
-of GTiff \
/content/drive/MyDrive/00390_00390.tif \
/content/drive/MyDrive/map-with-gcps.tif
```

Comment: CrossPost [How to process list of gcp points in gdal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023854/how-to-process-list-of-gcp-points-in-gdal-in-python)

Comment: see   [How to georeference an unreferenced aerial image using ground control points in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57384742/835653)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution for this. I am posting it.

```
# Read the coordinates in the CSV file
f=pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Input/00390_00390_modified.tif.points")
keep_col = ['mapX','mapY','pixelX', 'pixelY', 'enable', 'dX','dY', 'residual']
new_f = f[keep_col]
df = new_f.drop(columns=['enable','dX', 'dY', 'residual'])
col=['mapX','mapY', 'pixelX','pixelY']
modified_df = df[col]
modified_df['pixelY'] = modified_df['pixelY'] *(-1) 

# Create an empty GCP list
gcp_list=[]

# GCP coordinates list  
for index, rows in modified_df.iterrows():
   gcps = gdal.GCP(rows.mapX, rows.mapY, 1, rows.pixelX, rows.pixelY )
   gcp_list.append(gcps)
   print(gcps)
```